# Question on a corollary of excision theorem.

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

In page no. $125$ Hatcher has described a result as a corollary of excision theorem where he showed that if $(X,A)$ is a pair then the reduced homology group of $X \cup CA$ with respect to the tip of the cone $p$ (or the cone point $p$) is isomorphic to the relative homology group of $X$ with respect to $A.$ The argument what he gave is as follows $:$

> $$\widetilde {H_n} (X \cup CA) \approx H_n (X \cup CA, CA) \approx H_n ((X \cup CA) - \{p\}, CA - \{p\}) \approx H_n (X,A).$$
>
> Where the first isomorphism follows from the contractibility of $CA,$ the second isomorphism follows from the excision theorem and the third isomorphism follows from the fact that $CA - \{p\}$ deformation retracts onto $A.$

Now I have some questions in this regard.

I know that for any contractible space $Y$ we have $$H_n (Y) = \begin {cases} \mathbb Z & \text {if}\ n = 0 \\ 0 & \text {if}\ n \geq 1 \end {cases}$$

Using the fact that $CA$ is contractible and by long exactness of the following sequence of homology groups $$\cdots \rightarrow H_n (CA) \rightarrow H_n (X \cup CA) \rightarrow H_n (X \cup CA, CA) \rightarrow H_{n-1} (CA) \rightarrow H_{n-1} (X \cup CA) \rightarrow \cdots$$ I can able to conclude that $$H_n (X \cup CA) \approx H_n (X \cup CA, CA),\ \ \text {for all}\ n \geq 2.$$

But we know that for any space $Z$ $$\widetilde {H_n} (Z) \approx H_n (Z),\ \ \text {for all}\ n \geq 1.$$

Hence we have $$\widetilde {H_n} (X \cup CA) \approx H_n (X \cup CA) \approx H_n (X \cup CA, CA),\ \ \text {for all}\ n \geq 2.$$

But I have no idea how to prove it for $n = 0,1.$

> $\textbf {Question 1} :$ Why do we have $$\widetilde {H_n} (X \cup CA) \approx H_n (X \cup CA, CA)$$ $\text {for}\ n = 0,1\ $?

For the second isomorphism, in order to apply excision theorem  the only thing we need to make sure  is that whether $p$ is an interior point of $CA$ or not. I think that can be easily taken care of by taking a small enough neighborhood of $p$ which doesn't intersect $X.$

> $\textbf {Question 2} :$ Can it be justified  in some other nicer way?

For the third isomorphism, I can recall one of the propositions that our instructor discussed in the class which is as follows $:$

> $\textbf {Proposition} :$ Let $(X,A)$ and $(Y,B)$ be two pairs. Let $(f,g) : (X,A) \longrightarrow (Y,B)$ be a map with $f \in \textbf {Maps}\ (X,Y)$ and $g \in \textbf {Maps}\ (A,B)$ such that $f \big \rvert_{A} = g.$ If $f$ and $g$ are homotopy equivalences then $$H_n (X,A) \approx H_n (Y,B),\ \ \text {for all}\ n \geq 0.$$

The proof uses long exactness of the sequence of homology groups and five lemma.

Now here in this case we know that $CA - \{p\}$ deformation retracts onto $A$ by taking radial projection from the tip point $p.$ But that means  we have a retraction $r : CA - \{p\} \longrightarrow A$ which is a homotopy equivalence. So if it extends to a homotopy equivalence $s : (X \cup CA) - \{p\} \longrightarrow X$ then we are through.

> $\textbf {Question 3} :$ Does there exist a homotopy equivalence  $s : (X \cup CA) - \{p\} \longrightarrow X$ such that $s \big \rvert_{CA - \{p\}} = r\ $?

As I am beginner of this topic, I really need some help in understanding the result. Any suggestion regarding this will be warmly appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

The way to show the original claim for small $n$ is to use a homotopy equivalence of pairs (your proposition.) Note that

$$(X \cup CA,*) \hookrightarrow (X \cup CA,CA)$$

is a homotopy equivalence of pairs, and therefore $\tilde{H}_n(X \cup CA) \cong H_n(X \cup CA,*) \cong H_n(X \cup CA,CA).$

---

The second isomorphism *is* excision. Basically, take a small neighborhood $U$ around $p$. Then by excision we have

$$H_n(X \cup CA,CA) \cong H_n(X \cup CA \setminus U,CA \setminus U).$$

Now use your proposition to instead use $p$ in the place of $U$.

---

For question three: yes. Pushing down on the cylinder $CA \setminus p$  to its base will work. You extend it by having it be the identity on all of $X$.

Comment: Do you mean to take the identity map on $X \cup CA$ and restrict it to $*\ $?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Yes, thats basically correct. The map $X \cup CA \to X \cup CA$ is the identity. Its restriction to $p$ is the inclusion of a point into $CA$. Note that these are both homotopy equivalences since $* \hookrightarrow CA$ is a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: If we take $\text {id}_{X \cup CA}$ and restrict it to $*$ then will it not give the inclusion $* \hookrightarrow CA$ which is homotopy equivalence since $CA$ is contractible?

Comment: It will. ${}{}{}$

Comment: For the third isomorphism, if we take the homotopy $H$ defined by $$H([a,s],t) = (1 - t) [a,1 - st] + t [a,s(1-t)]$$ then will it work?

Comment: Looks good to me. The most important thing is that if s=0, then the map does nothing for all t.

Comment: Then my homotopy will not work. For $s = 0,$ it is  not giving the same value for all $t.$ Can you please provide an explicit homotopy? If we extend it to $X \cup CA$ by taking identity on $X$ then how can we show that it is continuous? I am in a fix at this stage. The usual way to show such maps are continuous is by using Pasting lemma. Right?

Comment: F_t[x,s]=[x,(1-t)s] should work.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. But how do you extend it to the whole of $X\ $? Do you mean when $s = 0$ then we take $x \in X$ and when $s \gt 0$ then we take $x \in A\ $? If we let $X \times \{0\}$ to be the copy $X$ sitting inside $X \cup CA$ containing $A \times \{0\}$ which is a copy of $A$ sitting inside $CA$ and hence in $X \cup CA.$

Comment: For the second isomorphism, I think we can take a neighborhood of $p$ which pulls back to an open cylindrical portion of the cylinder of $X$ which further pulls back to an open subset of $X \times I$ which is of the form $X \times (1-t_0,1],$ for some $0 \lt t_0 \lt 1.$ Then by quotient topology it follows that the neighborhood is open and now we can directly apply excision theorem to have the required result because now we know $p$ is an interior point of $CA.$

Comment: @Anacardium. I've said already, you extend by the identity on $X$.  Your last comment is perfectly good. In fact there is no need to use $X \cup CA \setminus \{p\}$ at all. You could simply delete the neighborhood that you selected and apply the homotopy as usual.